# how to handle the onbackpressed when configuration changes with for example a master-detail layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, tablet, back-stack

I'm trying to find information about how to write the code behind the onbackpressed in for example a master-detail layout. Just like in the android gmail app.

Let's say we have this situation:

1. You hold the tablet in landscape mode (screen has two fragments , on
   the left, you have the inboxes and the labels and on the right you
   have your list of mails)
2. You click on one of the mails and the list of mails will move to the
   left and the details of the email will be on the right.
3. Now I rotate my tablet and we will see only the details of the mail.

What kind of code will be on the onbackpressed method at this moment?

Pressing the backbutton will bring me back to first screen (inboxes + list of mails) But my last transaction in landscape mode was was removing the inboxes, moving the list to the left and add the details of the email to the right.

Just popping the backstack will not work in these situaties right? because we are popping transactions that were used for landscape mode?

Is the app just working with one activity ? Or is it having more activities? And than working with tagging the parent. Or a combination?

Comment: There is a concept of parent activity in Android. Its well referenced in the Docs. Although I am not sure if its applicable in case of Fragments. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Comment: true, I also saw that one. So maybe it's a combination? That when you rotate to portrait mode, that you get in another activity? And when you press back, you get to the parent activity. And when you rotate it again, you get in the master-detail activity again? ... It's all so confusing! haha

Comment: Yes a bit confusing but if you experiment around, you will get the desired result, I have however not had a chance to check on the functionality, but just that somewhere it was at the back of my mind.